# How to fill in Pine Script?

Tags: fill, pine-script

I'm trying to fill the areas between the standard deviations with colors but I get this error:

```
line 24: Cannot call 'fill' with arguments (series[float], series[float], color=const color); available overloads: fill(hline, hline, series[color], input integer, const string, const bool, string) => void; fill(plot, plot, series[color], input integer, const string, const bool, input integer, string) => void
```

I've tried various combinations of setting values and the plot to variables, but can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.  Any help appreciated.

```
//@version=4
study("My Script", overlay = true

hRange1 = close + stdev(close, 5)
hRange2 = close + (stdev(close,5)*2)
hRange3 = close + (stdev(close,5)*3)

lRange1 = close - stdev(close, 5)
lRange2 = close - (stdev(close,5)*2)
lRange3 = close - (stdev(close,5)*3)

plot(hRange1,style=plot.style_stepline)
plot(hRange2,style=plot.style_stepline)
plot(hRange3,style=plot.style_stepline)

plot(lRange1,style=plot.style_stepline)
plot(lRange2,style=plot.style_stepline)
plot(lRange3,style=plot.style_stepline)

fill(hRange1, hRange2, color=color.green)
```

Answer (score 3):

fill() can fill between two hlines or two plots. Your code doesn't work because you are trying to fill the space between two series (hRange1 and hRange2) instead of plots that draw these series. For your code to work, refer to plot objects specifically, e.g.:

```
p1 = plot(hRange1,style=plot.style_stepline)
p2 = plot(hRange2,style=plot.style_stepline)    
fill(p1, p2, color=color.green)
```